# How define conditional "Field Selection" in mongodb 'find()' query?

Tags: search, mongodb, conditional-statements, selection, field

Is it possible to conditionally specify the fields returned by the query.  Here is my use case:  I have an object with nested user conversations as follows:

```
{
  "_id" : "someId",
  user_id: 'user1',
  conversations: 
  [ 
    { 
      user_id: 'user2',
      comments: 
      [    
        { 
          user_id: 'user2',
          text: 'Hi user1' 
        },
        { 
          user_id: 'user1',
          text: 'Hi user2' 
        },
      ] 
    }, 
    { 
      user_id: 'user3',
      comments: 
      [    
        { 
          user_id: 'user3',
          text: 'Hi user1' 
        }
      ]
    }, 
  ]
}
```

I would like to allow all users to search for and view all objects but not conversations they don't own.  Something as follows:

```
findObj = function(criteria, user, callback) {
    Object.find({criteria}, {conversation: 
       {
          if (user_id == user.id || conversations[].user_id = user.id) {1} else {0} 
       } }
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
-Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can get all users that have conversations that involve user X like so :

```
db.users.find({$or:[{user_id: X}, {'conversations.user_id':x}]})
```

However this will not do what you want. You're running into a problem with your schema. You have to remove conversations from the user objects and store them in a dedicated collection that allows for queries on specific conversations seperately.

Comment: Thanks Remon, you are right, moving the conversations out of my object would work.  Thanks for your reply, -Eric